# Can we graduate please? :)

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

*Seeing as to that we are in principle in the green on the Area 51 [statistics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42572/aviation) (I know these are not exact) and have been for some time.*

I feel we have what is a solid community represented by a fairly distributed group. These have varying areas and levels of expertise that should ensure that the quality of the site is ensured. We have almost a scale of magnitude more hits a day from the stats than is required, indicating that we are a popular medium that perhaps doesn't deserve a 'beta' tag.

**As such, I'm wondering if we can:**

- Graduate!
- How far away we would be from such a step.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/265657

Comment: one loss of graduating will be many users losing privileges. For example, rep required to cast close votes will escalate to 3000..

Comment: [When this site graduates, what will happen to user reps and privileges?](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/when-this-site-graduates-what-will-happen-to-user-reps-and-privileges)

Comment: @anshabhi That's not an issue at all. We have users who even have up to 50k rep. It's not that big of a deal.

Comment: hey the number of those users is "1" .. there are only 51 users with 3k+ rep at present, 5 times less than 226 users with 500+ rep..

Comment: @anshabhi Sure but if you look at the [list of people who've done the most close-vote reviews](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats), all but two of the top 20 have >3000 rep so would be able to continue voting. Most users with 500-2999 rep don't do a lot of close voting so them losing that ability wouldn't make a big difference to the site.

Comment: @DavidRicherby there's a difference between people who have reviewed the close votes and those who have voted to close. I rarely hit the review queue, so I've made significantly more close votes than what is shown there. (I also wouldn't be hit by the 3k close rep cut, _just_, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: @FreeMan Good point. I'd forgotten that the stats I linked to only include people who went via the review queue, which makes them rather less useful.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not worried about the close/RO votes. I think the 50+ >3k users will be able to handle that just fine. The 15k for protection and 20k for delete/undelete votes might be more problematic, though, considering we have a grand total of 6 20k users and even one of our mods is < 15k (not that it would matter for him, but is just demonstrates that a lot of our regulars are < 15k.) Then again, we don't really protect or undelete all that many posts, so it might still be manageable.

Comment: @reirab Also, of course, us mods can delete / undelete pretty quickly too if it is flagged.

Comment: @Lnafziger Right, yeah, that was mostly what I was referring to by the "it might still be manageable" (especially since it usually takes 3 votes and 2 of the 6 people who could vote _are_ mods. :) )

Comment: It's pretty simple. We meet the criteria, so we're on the path to graduating sooner or later. Probably sooner than later.

Comment: We just graduated so I'm marking this [tag:status-completed] and protecting it (not that our Meta is very active).

Answer (score 10):

Update: **Yes, we can**, and in fact we have reached the design-independent graduation milestone.  See [Congratulations, Aviation is graduating!](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2844/congratulations-aviation-is-graduating) for more information.

---

The [new design-independent graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263905/265657) that started going into effect in September has a basic criteria of 10 Q/day as a threshold.  If you look at [our site-analytics page](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/site-analytics) (5000 rep required) you can see that our average Q/day is around 10 but we aren't consistently at (or above) it.
<s>I'd estimate (and I'm no authority on this) that we are close to the metric to qualify for design-independent graduation but not quite at it.</s>

With design-independent graduation<s>, when it happens,</s> all we'll see is "beta" dropped from the site name and elections held for moderators.  The site will otherwise look the same and reputation levels will remain the same.  In short, not a lot will change in the short term.

Comment: (Although note that DIG puts you on track for eventually getting a design and raised privilege levels: it's basically just like being put on the queue used to be.)

Comment: `5000 rep required`...until we graduate and then have this increased to 25k

Comment: Two thoughts cross my mind: (1) Hasn't the 10 question thing been waived if slightly low, assuming quality and community is sufficient (both have pretty decent Stats) and (2) I am fairly convinced the site development would benefit from a more individual aviation design and this would also contribute to increasing the usage further when it is rolled out.

Comment: Can we get a graduation-independent design instead? :) In all seriousness, I'm not sure how helpful the rep increase would be at present, though I agree that a design would be nice. There are currently only 6 20k users. I think we'd still have plenty of people able to cast close/ro votes, but we might be a bit short on number of users with some of the higher-rep privileges.

Comment: @MikeFoxtrot the new DIG guidelines are new and only a few sites have gone through it, so I'm not sure exactly how they are sticking to the new numbers or even how the queue or process is moving along.  While DIG may not be too far away (no idea), getting a site design is most likely quite far away as there are plenty of sites that are waiting for that (e.g. see code review.se which has undergone the new DIG process).

Comment: @reirab I don't think there is an instead anymore, as I understand it the DIG *is* the new process and will be the first step toward a design and rep increases for all un-graduated beta sites that are deemed ready to graduate.

Comment: Since the custom design seems to be a repeat topic, I [posted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267772/add-site-icon-in-beta-website-banner) a question on meta and asked if they could enhance the design a little without too much work to make it more bearable.

Comment: Having watched some of the wailing and gnashing of teeth over at Code Review about graduation, 1) removing the Beta label and 2) getting a design seem to be the highlights of graduation. 1 is easy, **2 has been the log jam all along**. Ensuring enough high rep users to cover all the maintenance issues is important, but I _think_ we've got that covered.