# Congratulations, Aviation is graduating!

Tags: discussion

It's a big day, [and I know you folks have been waiting](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/can-we-graduate-please). You've been cleared for graduation by the Stack Exchange Community Team! Aviation met our threshold for [graduation-worthy sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) and after a review, the Community Team determined that you're good to go. Reaching 'mature community' status is a big milestone, and you should be very proud.

What does this mean exactly? Graduation works in two phases. Starting today, you'll receive the following benefits:

- You will soon have an election for community-voted moderators - there is some backlog here as the elections for some of the first-wave sites have also had to be delayed. Elections for you and the other sites in this wave will start being scheduled in December.
- You will no longer see the "beta" label attached to your site's name
- You will become eligible for question migration paths with the rest of the network
- You will soon be able to select your own community ads. We're very close to the new year and the new ad cycle, and we have some exciting changes planned for these as well. These, too, will begin in December or early January so that you may enjoy the new changes.

The site will still receive a full design from one of our designers, which will be packaged with an increase in the amount of reputation needed to access each privilege. It's no secret that our backlog for site designs is long, so instead of making you wait to receive all the parts of graduation at once, we wanted to [give you the things we could give](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260754/feedback-requested-design-independent-graduation) you now. We think we've hammered out most of the bugs in the process,, but there are still likely to be some left -  so if you come across anything out of place, please report it on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) using the [graduating-sites] tag.

This site has reached this point because of your generous contributions. Together, you've created a valuable resource that helps people. Congratulations on all you've accomplished.

Comment: Now you can finally launch the design [prepared by this day](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/new-aviation-site-design).

Comment: @nicael NEEDZ MOAR BOMBZ!

Comment: Is this when I bring up that we definitely should be using N9-M silhouettes for the up and down vote arrows?  (A B-2 would work in a pinch, very similar ;) )

Comment: Surely C150 or C172 planform up-and-down arrows would be more appropriate? Every pilot starts somewhere, and they look very stereotypically "Plane-y"!

Comment: Or maybe the space shuttle. We all need to have dreams!

Comment: Ouchh!! Need to build up more reps fast!!

Comment: @Landak Sure, but they aren't really shaped like arrows, where as a swept wing is.

Comment: @Landak I did a but more of a study of it in an earlier post.  If you have some ideas for how to make a Cessna 172 work, post them there.  I do like me a good GA plane, if it can be made to look like an arrow you'd have my support :).  http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/323/custom-vote-up-down-arrows

Comment: Graduation, finally!

Comment: Nice! We made it!

Comment: Yes, we made it!

Comment: how do we find out when the voting takes place?

Comment: @rbp Elections won't be happening for some time - either late December or early January.

Comment: Yesssss! Finally! :D

Answer (score 7):

[Obligatory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kw-_Ew5bVxs)

Answer (score 2):

Does this mean we will actually lose privileges we already have? Or just that any future privileges gained (for existing or new users) will be at higher reputation milestones?

Comment: rep thresholds wont go up until we get a design but yes, you will lose privileges you no longer qualify for.

Comment: This makes me sad :(

Comment: Time to hunt more rep!

Comment: haha unfortunately I try to avoid answering unless I'm sure, and Aviation *tends* to be fairly black-and-white, so I find it tricky to deliberately acquire rep

Comment: I think you should have posted this as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: @Federico But it wasn't really a question... this seemed to fit better. I wouldn't post as this way on the non-meta site, but where there's a non-questioning-question on Meta, it seems more acceptable.

Comment: @JonStory at your rep level you'll only lose access to editing tag wikis without review/approving tag wiki edits and moderator tools.  It may be quite a while before the rep increase happens (big design backlog) though.

Comment: Asking a good relevant question is a way to contribute and earn reps

Comment: will we be notified somehow?